# How to calculate Cell phone bill in java, calculation issues

Tags: java

My task is to calculate monthly cell phone bill in java, I am new to java and am still learning. I can't seem to understand the calculations and how to get there. I have named all variables and constants and initiliazed them, now I just need to make the calculations to find the cost of the total bill. the output i'm trying to reach is : run: minutes used = 675 text messages sent/recieved = 1031 data used = 605 megabytes. DO you have a data play? (Y/n) : Y Do you have a text message plan (y/n)?: Y 
Monthly cell phone charges : Monthly plan = 39.99 Text message plan = 15.00 Data plan = 20.00 Addidtional minutes charged = 79.85 charge for data overage = 40.00

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);

        final double MONTHLY_PLAN_VOICE;
        final int ALLOWABLE_MINUTES;
        final double ADDITIONAL_MINUTE_RATE;
        final double TEXT_MSG_PLAN;
        final double TEXT_MSG_RATE;
        final double DATA_PLAN_RATE;
        final int ALLOWABLE_DATA_INCR;

        MONTHLY_PLAN_VOICE = 39.99; //double cause of decimal
        ALLOWABLE_MINUTES = 500; // int because no need for decimal
        ADDITIONAL_MINUTE_RATE = 0.45; // has decimal 
        TEXT_MSG_PLAN = 15.00; // rate could very depending on user input(double)
        TEXT_MSG_RATE = 0.12; // rate could very depending on user input (double)
        DATA_PLAN_RATE = 20.00; // double cause of decimal
        ALLOWABLE_DATA_INCR = 300; //int cause its an increment

        String minutes;
        System.out.print("Enter the number of minutes used this month: ");
        minutes = user_input.next();
        String texts;
        System.out.print("Do you have a text message plan? (Y/N): ");

        texts = user_input.next();
        System.out.print("Enter the number of sent and recieved texts: ");
        texts = user_input.next();
        String data;
        System.out.print("Do you have a Data plan? (Y/N): ");
        data = user_input.next();
        System.out.print("Enter the amount of Data used: ");
        data = user_input.next();



        if (ALLOWABLE_DATA_INCR < 300) 
        {
        System.out.print("The Cost of data is 20.00$ ");
        }
        else 
        {    
        System.out.println("The cost of data is 40.00$" );
        }


        if (ALLOWABLE_MINUTES > 500)
        {
        System.out.print("");
        }
```

Comment: the code above is what i tried, i don't understand how to have different total costs if the user has or doesnt have a text plan/data plan/ minutes or exceeeds the limits of that. @Shiven

Comment: @Shiven i don't know where to go from here, i think i have the right idea but i do not know the next step :/

Answer (score 0):

First my personal option is to keep your code clean and initiate and assign in one step:

```
 final double MONTHLY_PLAN_VOICE = 39.99; //double cause of decimal
```

Secondly the US Dollar sign "$" should always be used as a prefix to a number. ex $5.99
Your print statement reads:

```
 System.out.print("The Cost of data is 20.00$ ");
```

I recommend just changing each of those to look a little more professional.

```
 System.out.print("The cost of data is $20.00.");
```

Now to answer your question.
To find the total create a new variable of type double. :

```
double totalMonthlyBill = 0;
```

Now in each of your if else statements add the cost per each part of the bill to this total variable.

for example:

```
 if (ALLOWABLE_DATA_INCR < 300) 
    {
    System.out.print("The Cost of data is 20.00$ ");
    totalMonthlyBill += 20;
    }
    else 
    {    
    System.out.println("The cost of data is 40.00$" );
    totalMonthlyBill += 40;
    }
```

The += will add or subtract if negative the value of (totalMonthlyBill) by whatever is passed. you can use += with 2 variable or passing a int or double ext.

assuming Variable1 and Variable2 are initialized previously and both have been given a value of not null

```
Variable1 += Variable2;
Variable1 += 2;
```

This is the same as:

```
Variable1 = Variable1 + Variable2;
Variable1 = Variable1 + 2;
```

But in your case since you have a running total and will be defining the cost based of each step this can easily be achived by defining a total variable and then using += in each if/else statement to add the value to the total which you can then call later for your final price

```
System.out.println("Total monthly bill: " + totalMonthlyBill);
```

Hope this solves the problem.

Comment: Glad it helped. Give me that up arrow for the answer if that solved your problem and if not let me know anything else thats giving you trouble on this assignment and I would be happy to help.

Comment: i do have another question, i have to do the same thing that i did with data for text messages and minutes.. but the tricky part with this is, if the user doesnt have a text plan or excedes the 500 maximum of minutes it adds to the total bill. for example, for each minute over 500 minutes it charges $0.45, and for if you dont have a text message plan it charges $0.12 for each text. how do i put this in to the code @LEnc95

Comment: Do you know how to use booleans? Let me give you a example to solve that method.

Answer (score 0):

I had to create a new answer in order to submit all the code it was too long for a comment but take a look at this and comment if you have any questions on how this works but I think this is what you want.

```
    boolean textPlan;
    double numTexts = 0;

    String texts;
    System.out.print("Do you have a text message plan? (Y/N): ");
    texts = user_input.next();
    if (texts.equalsIgnoreCase("y")){
        textPlan = true;
    }
    else{
        textPlan = false;
    }
    System.out.print("Enter the number of sent and recieved texts: ");
    numTexts = user_input.next();

    if (textPlan && numTexts <= 500){
        totalMonthlyBill += TEXT_MSG_PLAN;
    }
    else if (textPlan && numTexts > 500){
        numTexts -= 500; 
        totalMonthlyBill += (numTexts * TEXT_MSG_RATE);
    }
    else{
        totalMonthlyBill += (numTexts * TEXT_MSG_RATE);
    }
```

Comment: i don't think so but i think i get the idea, i just am not sure how to add it to my code, and i think ive done a horrible job explaining the question to you, i wish i could just show you the hw problem :(

Comment: it says cant make a string into a double :/